# How to know page faults happened on a specific memory mapped area

Tags: linux, memory-management, kernel, page-fault

The total page faults on a process can be obtained by /proc//statm, but how can I know how many happened on a specific mmaped area? Thanks

Comment: I'd try perf_event_open with PERF_COUNT_SW_PAGE_FAULTS and PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR. If you really need all the faults, you might try using sample_period = 1 (?).

Comment: Thanks @ysdx, but can that be set to a range of address or just a single address? Because I want to know page fault happens on a range of memory address.

Comment: It would give you the address of each page fault. You then have to find the corresponding VMA.

Comment: @ysdx, that would be enough for me. I can parse the address my self.

Comment: @ysdx, is the PERF_SAMPLE_ADDRE can be used with perf command?